# ImageView out of dialog bounds

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I tried do something like this:
[image: Image for screen]

And problem is with icon that go out from dialog bounds.Im understood that I can make one RelativeLayout for all screen,and inner for this dialog,in bigger I must put my icon and try to make them in the head of dialog.Correct?
I tried this but what I have is my icon was like a background of dialog,not at dialog.Like this:
[image: my result]

what can I do to change that?

my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/rlimageforimage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/emilypic"

            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/outsideCimage"
            android:src="@drawable/cicon"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/dialog_icon"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/dialog_icon"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/dialog_icon"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/dialog_icon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_clear_black_18dp"
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/LLTitleandNick"
android:layout_below="@id/rlimageforimage"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/title_color"
        android:text="Lily Martinson"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dialog_nickname"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="lilmartini"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/LLTitleandNick"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:id="@+id/LLFollowers"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/image_like"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_18dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Followers"
            android:text="Followers"
            />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_follow"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_walk_black_18dp"
    />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Following"

            />

        </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_below="@id/LLFollowers"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/LLwithButtons"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LLFollowers"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"


        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_question_answer_black_18dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cicon"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"


            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/ic_person_add_black_18dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your xml

Comment: I am 99% sure you are going to have to do a custom view to get that icon to look like that.

Comment: @zgc7009 is right... It seems a Custom View, look for some new code of Material Design, for example: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/30,